# Каким образом вернуть измененный список из БД с помощью rxjava?

Tags: kotlin, rxjava

Есть метод, который возвращает данные в виде `Flowable<MutableList<Item>>`. Метод `itemDao.getAllItems()` выдаёт список в виде `Flowable<MutableList<ItemEntity>>` из БД. Для конвертация объекта из **ItemEntity** в **Item** использую свой класс **Mapper** с помощью метода `mapDetailItem`, куда кидаю список деталей из другой таблицы, которые затем будут добавлены в объект **Item**, а затем будет возвращен сам объект, у которого уже есть заполненное поле **List**.

Каким образом можно это провернуть с каждым элементом и в итоге вернуть список `MutableList<Item>` вместо `MutableList<ItemEntity>`

```
override fun loadLocalItems(): Flowable<MutableList<Item>> {
        return itemDao.getAllItems()
                .map { list ->
                    Flowable.fromIterable(list).map {
                        mapper.mapDetailItem(it, itemDao.getAllDetailItemsById(it.idItem))
                    }
                }
 }
```

C одним элементом я делаю таким образом:

```
return itemDao.getItemById(id).map { mapper.mapDetailItem(it, itemDao.getAllDetailItemsById(it.idItem)) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если упростить ответ, то нужно просто:

```
override fun loadLocalItems(): Flowable<MutableList<Item>> =
    itemDao.getAllItems()
            .map { list ->
                list.map {
                    mapper.mapDetailItem(it, itemDao.getAllDetailItemsById(it.idItem))
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

1)Можно воспользоваться функцией вида

```
fun Flowable<MutableList<Item>>.toItemEntity() {
    this.list.map { it as ItemEntity }
}
```

Тогда вызов будет таким

```
loadLocalItems().toItemEntity()
```

2)Т.к. метод map возвращает

```
Flowable<MutableList<Item>>
```

значит код ниже

```
mapper.mapDetailItem(it, itemDao.getAllDetailItemsById(it.idItem))
```

возвращает Item -> таким образом можно просто вернуть ItemEntity, например:

```
open class ItemEntity
class Item: ItemEntity() {
    val k = 1
}

fun getItems(): MutableList<ItemEntity> {
    return arrayListOf(ItemEntity(), ItemEntity())
}
fun loadItems2(): MutableList<ItemEntity> {
    return getItems()
        .map { it -> mapToItem(it) }
        .toMutableList()
}
fun mapToItem(item: ItemEntity):ItemEntity {
    return ItemEntity()
}
```

строка

```
.map { it -> mapToItem(it) }
```

как раз возвращает ItemEntity